# JSON output including more columns than it should

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, json

I'm retrieving data from a MSSQL database with PHP, I want to format it to JSON because that's the only way for me to develop a chart (with the help of **am charts**).

This is my code:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: applicaton/json');
    $serverName = "server\sqlexpress";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"myDB", "UID"=>"myUID", "PWD"=>"myPWD");

    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if( $conn==true ) {
 //echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));}

//QUERY

$sql = "SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, JOBTYPE from directory ORDER BY JOBTYPE";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);//, $params);

if( $stmt) {
    // echo "Statement executed.<br>\n";
}
else
{
    echo "error in statement execution.\n";
    die (print_r (sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

//PRINT ROWS
$data = array();
while ($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH))
{
$data[] = $row;
//echo $row['LASTNAME']. ' | ' .$row['FIRSTNAME']. ' | ' .$row['JOBTYPE']. "<br>" ;
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I supposed that my output data would be formatted like this:

```
[{"LASTNAME": "MEINE",
   "FIRSTNAME": "KLAUS",
   "JOBTYPE": "LEADVOICE"
},
{"LASTNAME": "SCHENKER",
   "FIRSTNAME": "RUDOLF",
   "JOBTYPE": "RYTHMGUITAR"
}]
```

But it gets outputted like this:

```
[{"0":"KLAUS",
"FIRSTNAME":"KLAUS",
"1":"MEINE",
"LASTNAME":"MEINE",
"2":" LEADVOICE",
"JOBTYPE":" LEADVOICE"
},
{"0":"RUDOLF",
"FIRSTNAME":"RUDOLF",
"1":"SCHENKER",
"LASTNAME":"SCHENKER",
"2":" RYTHMGUITAR",
"JOBTYPE":" RYTHMGUITAR"
}]
```

What and why is happening?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace below line

```
$data[] = $row;
```

With

```
$row_data['LASTNAME'] = $row['LASTNAME'];
$row_data['FIRSTNAME] = $row['FIRSTNAME'];
$row_data['JOBTYPE'] = $row['JOBTYPE'];

array_push($data,$row_data);
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, thank you very much!

So in case that I retrieve another table with another fields I'll have to do it like your example, right?

Comment: Yes, follow the same when you want to store few values from database table.